# Python: What is a faster way to check if items in a large list are not in another large list?

Tags: python, list, performance, bigdata

I have two lists:

- **old_data** has a length of 180,000.
- **updated_data** has a length of 184,000.
- Both lists contain IDs which are *string values*.
- There is a lot of overlap in IDs stored within the lists but I need to know which ones are no longer stored in **updated_data** so that I can say those IDs are not longer active in an SQL server.

Therefore, I need to check for any items in **old_data** that are not in **updated_data** and save them to a separate list, let's call it **inactive_data**.

I have the following code currently which is highly time-consuming and inefficient:

```
# Initialize list for no-longer active IDs to be saved into.
inactive_data = []

# Iteratively check if all IDs in old data are still in updated data.
# If they are not, add them to the list.
for Id in old_data:
    
    if Id not in updated_data:
        
        inactive_data.append(Id)
```

To run this code, it took approx. 45 minutes. I would to know how I could drastically reduce the time. If you have any suggestions please let me know!

Comment: If the order is not important you can convert the lists to sets and find the difference: `set(old_data) - set(updated_data)`

Comment: [Just to provide an example of using sets](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoMS8lP5eLKz8nJT4lsSRRwVYhGiKmB6Iy80o0DHQMDaBAUyEtv0ghXiEzD6QxPVXD0AIsHMtVWgDUnUqeGQZQM7gKikBqc1LzNIpTSzRgTtLUBfGQLdDU1Pz/HwA)

Comment: @Mark that just reduced it to 0.5 seconds. That blows my mind. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual and easy way is to turn one or both of the `list` into a `set`.

An alternate way is to sort both lists and compare them element by element.  Once they're ordered, the comparison is quick because it's O(n).

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use a set(), sortedcontainers and then use set operations to do the diff. If your dataset is more complex, you might need to index id using a dict, then use a set of the keys.

```
# from sortedcontainers import SortedSet, SortedDict
old_data      = set(map(str,range(180000)))
updated_data  = set(map(str,range(184000)))
inactive_data = updated_data - old_data
active_data   = updated_data & old_data
print("inactive_data: ", len(inactive_data), set(list(inactive_data)[0:10]))
print("active_data:   ", len(active_data),   set(list(active_data)[0:10]))
```

```
inactive_data:    4000 {'181439', '181023', '183834', '180575', '182003', '183226', '180134', '183697', '181968', '181804'}
active_data:    180000 {'54276', '128822', '91802', '8678', '118826', '97510', '22786', '30341', '88711', '137764'}

time 0.609s
```

- NOTE: sortedcontainers.SortedSet is half the speed of unordered set()